# Automatic video playback in ViewPager and Recyclerview like instagram

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, instagram, android-videoview

How to automatically play video in `ViewPager`, which is a child of `RecyclerView`, and pause it when it leaves the screen, such as Instagram. So that there is no out of memory risk and smooth scrolling is done well.

[image]

Comment: Have u got any solution for it

Comment: Rajan1404930 No.

Answer (score 1):

You can use View.OnAttachStateChangeListener interface in your ViewHolder.

onViewAttachedToWindow() : Called when the view is attached to a window.
onViewDetachedFromWindow() :  Called when the view is detached from a window.

```
class VideoViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
        init {
            itemView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
        }
        override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
            //Start video
        }
        override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
            //Pause Video
        }
    }
```